# How to update values in cosmosdb as output using azure stream analutics?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

at first event I get data like below

```
{
'product_name':'hamam',
'quantity':'100'
}
```

at second I get data like below

```
{
'product_name':'hamam',
'quantity':'70'
}
```

here I wanna update the values in cosmos db, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you share what have you tried? Do you want to do it from a VM? What kind of application would pass around the information? Are you aware of Cosmos DB [Partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data)?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? I don't know why you opened a new case.

Answer (score 0):

ASA supports `upserts` feature for cosmos db if your data contains a unique document id.(Your sample data seems does not have it) Please see this [paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-documentdb-output#upserts-from-stream-analytics) about upserts in ASA for cosmos db.

Some excerpt as below:

Stream Analytics integration with Azure Cosmos DB allows you to insert or update records in your container based on a given Document ID column.

If the incoming JSON document has an existing ID field, that field is automatically used as the Document ID column in Cosmos DB and any subsequent writes are handled as such, leading to one of these situations:

- unique IDs lead to insert
- duplicate IDs and 'Document ID' set to 'ID' leads to upsert
- duplicate IDs and 'Document ID' not set leads to error, after the
  first document