# How to update values in cosmos db using azure stream analytics query language?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I'm looking to update data using azures stream analytics query lanuage,
for example,
at the first event, my data will be like below,

```
{
 'Name':'product1',
'sales':100
}
```

at the second event

```
{
  'name':'product1'
   'sales':200
}
```

and I wanna sum sales for both of the event,
for example,

```
{
  'name':'product1',
  'sales':200
}
```

Comment: sum is 300,not 200,am i right?

Comment: If you want to update the document in cosmos DB based on new inputs, You can use azure triggering functions. And you can set Unique Key in the cosmos DB container while creation to avoid duplicates.

Comment: yes I wanna sum this, 100 + 200 = 300

Answer (score 0):

I take this case as an extension of this case:[How to update values in cosmosdb as output using azure stream analutics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699026/how-to-update-values-in-cosmosdb-as-output-using-azure-stream-analutics/57702189#57702189.According) to the words i mentioned before, ASA supports upserts feature for cosmos db if your data contains a unique document id. For you, if your `Name` property is unique key, it could be applied.

However,you wanna `sum` function now, [Azure Function output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#azure-functions) in ASA could be applied.You could pass the unique `Name` and the `sales` as params into Azure Function,then query the data with unique `Name` and do the sum calculate.Finally,update the data by the unique `Name`.